# How i can return a customized response in a FormRequest class in Laravel 5.5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation, laravel-5.5, laravel-request, laravel-response

I am making an API and i want return the array of errors with a format as the one that `$validator->errors();` generates when i validate the request by the manual way. But i cant manipulate the response. I wanna find thhe correct way to make it.

This could be done in Laravel 5.4 with the `formatErrors` method and including the `Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator` class in the FormRequest class but for version 5.5 it does not work. I do not know how to do it.

**This is my Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\ProductRequest;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use App\Product;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(ProductRequest $request)
    {
        $products = Product::where('code', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->input('search').'%')
        ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->input('search').'%')
        ->paginate(10);
        $products->withPath($request->fullUrl());
        return $products;
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(ProductRequest $request)
    {
        $product = new Product($request->validated());
        $product->save();
        return response('', 201);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $product = Product::find($id);
        return response($product, 200);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(ProductRequest $request, $id)
    {
        $product = Product::find($id);
        $product->fill($request->validated());
        $product->save();
        return response('', 200);
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $product = Product::find($id);
        $product->delete();
        return response('', 204);
    }
}
```

**This is mi FormRequest class**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

class ProductRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        switch($this->method())
        {
            case 'GET':
            {
                return [
                    'code' => 'string',
                    'name' => 'string',
                ];
            } break;
            case 'POST':
            {
                return [
                    'code' => 'required|unique:Products,code',
                    'name' => 'required',
                    'description' => 'required',
                    'quantity' => 'required|min:0',
                    'price' => 'required|numeric',
                    'extemp' => [
                        Rule::in(['tax', 'free']),
                    ]
                ];
            } break;
            case 'PUT':
            {
                return [
                    'code' => 'unique:products,code,'.$this->route('product'),
                    'name' => 'string:min:1',
                    'description' => 'string|min:1',
                    'quantity' => 'integer|min:0',
                    'price' => 'numeric',
                    'extemp' => [
                        Rule::in(['tax', 'free']),
                    ],
                ];
            } break;
            case 'PATCH': break;
            case 'DELETE': break;
            default:
            {
                return [];
            } break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the error messages for the defined validation rules.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            //Product
            'code.required' => 'El :attribute es obligatorio.',
            'code.unique' => 'El :attribute ya se encuentra registrado.',
            'name.required' => 'El :attribute es obligatorio.',
            'name.min' => 'El :attribute es obligatorio.',
            'description.required' => 'El :attribute es obligatorio.',
            'description.min' => 'El :attribute es obligatorio.',
            'quantity.required' => 'La :attribute es obligatoria.',
            'quantity.integer' => 'La :attribute debe ser un número entero.',
            'quantity.min' => 'La :attribute debe ser al menos :min.',
            'price.required' => 'El :attribute es obligatorio.',
            'price.numeric' => 'El :attribute debe ser un valor numérico.',
            'extemp.in' => 'El :attribute seleccionado es inválido.',
        ];
    }
    public function attributes(){
        return [
            'code' => 'código',
            'name' => 'nombre',
            'description' => 'descripción',
            'quantity' => 'cantidad',
            'price' => 'precio',
            'extemp' => 'exento',
        ];
    }
}
```

**The Response what i have:**

```
{
    "message": "The given data was invalid.",
    "errors": {
        "code": [
            "El código es obligatorio."
        ],
        "name": [
            "El nombre es obligatorio."
        ],
        "description": [
            "El descripción es obligatorio."
        ],
        "quantity": [
            "La cantidad es obligatoria."
        ],
        "price": [
            "El precio es obligatorio."
        ]
    }
}
```

**The Response what i want** (with `$validator->errors();`)

```
[
    "El código es obligatorio.",
    "El nombre es obligatorio.",
    "El descripción es obligatorio.",
    "La cantidad es obligatoria.",
    "El precio es obligatorio."
]
```

Comment: Try this `$validator->errors()->all();`

Comment: @Maraboc is correct especially if its custom validation but for Form request, then that might not work

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have to **override** the `failedValidation()` method and issue the exception with the response what you want.
So, you need to use `Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator` and `Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException`  in the **RequestForm** class, and override the `failedValidation()` method:

```
protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator) { 
        throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json($validator->errors()->all(), 422)); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly!

Answer (score 4):

For this Need to override `failedValidation()` function in your Request file.

```
protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
{
    throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json([
      'errors' => $validator->errors(),
      'status' => false
    ], 422));
}
```

To make it work `use` these namespaces:

For laravel 5.4 and above:

```
 use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;

 use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;
```

[description here](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/search.html?search=HttpResponseException)

Below laravel 5.4:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Exception\HttpResponseException;
```

[description here](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/search.html?search=HttpResponseException)

Answer (score 2):

In my case i using Laravel 7 and change a little:

```
//add depences
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;

//override this method in your FormRequest
protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator){
  throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json($validator->errors(), 422)); 
}
```